# HttpServletRequest UTF-8 Encode

Tags: servlets

I have a problem with HttpServletRequest when I send a params which has a value = "Hành động". But I use 
   String categoryName = request.getParameter("categoryname");

Param categoryName will be "Hành ??ng". I don't understand that error.

Somebody help me???

Comment: What is encoding of html page and form? What locale is Java running?

Comment: I'm using spring 3 + resfult to call api. And I user Tomcat server.

Comment: If your system locale is not UTF8 then java will not work correctly with this encoding. If you use linux, you must set either LANG or LC_ALL system environment property before tomcat is started. For example export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 (replace en with vietnamese equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply following filter on your servlet:

```
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }

    if (chain != null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I used request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); ==> It wasn't successful. I use method GET.

Comment: Well, it may be too late to use it in servlet. I experienced similar situation and I resolved it with this filter. If something else touch the input stream before setting character encoding then this call has no effect.